# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de un botón en Android programaticamente?

Tags: java, android

Encontré un código que funciona pero `getColor()` es marcado cómo obsoleto, alguna otra alternativa que pueda utilizar?

Este es el código que encontré.

```
   button.setBackgroundColor(controller.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Es necesario tener la librería de soporte `23`o una superior, para obtener el color con el [getColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getColor(android.content.Context,%20int))

Su uso es
`ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);`

**Función de compatibilidad de versiones:**

```
public static final int getColor(Context context, int id) {
    final int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (version >= 23) {
        return ContextCompatApi23.getColor(context, id);
    } else {
        return context.getResources().getColor(id);
    }
}
```

Extraído de [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31590927/3464919)

Answer (score 1):

Hola una buena opcion pudiera ser la siguiente :D saludos

```
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```